# Repeating the call based on availability in Symbol ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was using ES6 Symbols iterator where when I am iterating I need to call next function each time to print the next items

Here's my code:

```js
var title = "Omkar";
var iterateIt = console.log(typeof title[Symbol.iterator]);
var iterable = title[Symbol.iterator]();

do {
  console.log(iterable.next().value);
} while (iterable.done)
```

It prints only `O`

but if I do 4 more times `console.log(iterable.next().value);` I get the value
Suppose I have String with more characters Example- **"Chewbacca"** then I have to do 9 times this same console. Why I have to call next everytime while my logic above says while it's not done get next value. If there is some way then please tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.done` property is on the object *returned by calling the iterable*, not on the iterable itself:

```js
var title = "Omkar";
var iterable = title[Symbol.iterator]();

let value, done;
do {
  ({ value, done } = iterable.next());
  if (!done) console.log(value);
} while (!done)
```

You might find it more convenient to use a `for..of` loop instead:

```js
var title = "Omkar";
for (const char of title) {
  console.log(char);
}
```

Comment: `do{
            console.log(iterable.next().value);  
           
        }while(!iterable.next().done)` 

Ok still this should have worked 

But I got `E` and `6`  why `S` got skipped

Comment: Each call of `.next()` returns the *next* `{value, done}` object. With that code, you'll be skipping every other character, because you're calling `.next` twice on each iteration.

Comment: Yes I know `for...of` but I want to know more about this Symbol iterator

Comment: You just have to call `.next()` *once* on each iteration, like in the first snippet in the answer.

Comment: Got it with deconstructing assignments I don't have to call .next twice therefore I skipped the next value

Comment: can you please tell why I need parathesis here `({ value, done } = iterable.next());` around ?

Comment: That's how you object-destructure into an existing variable. Without the parentheses, you'll get a `SyntaxError`

Comment: hmm...actually in react we do like this `const {a} = this.state;` I guess it has to do something with the scope

Comment: That's destructing into a *new* variable, so parentheses aren't needed. You need the parentheses when destructuring into an *existing* variable.